How to update room affiliation for a user using MongooseIm GraphQL API?
MongooseIM version: 6.2.1
Installed from: Official Docker
Erlang/OTP version: 25
Not able to modify User Affiliation to a MUC.
Steps to reproduce:
Create a Users A, B: (OK) as Admin User
mutation register_user {
    account {
        registerUser(
            domain: "DOMAIN"
            password: "PASSWORD"
            username: "USER-A/USER-B"
        ) {
            jid
            message
        }
    }
}

Create a MUC: (OK) as User B
mutation create_room {
  muc {
    createInstantRoom(
      nick: "USERNICK",
      room: "ROOM_NAME@group.host"
    ) {
      jid
      title
      private
      usersNumber
    }
  }
}

Update MUC properties: (OK) as User B
mutation change_room_configuration {
    muc {
        changeRoomConfiguration(
            room: "_store@group.localhost"
            config: {
                title: "TITLE"
                description: "DESCRIPTION"
                allowChangeSubject: true
                allowQueryUsers: true
                allowPrivateMessages: true
                allowVisitorStatus: true
                allowVisitorNickchange: true
                public: true
                publicList: true
                persistent: true
                moderated: false
                membersByDefault: true
                membersOnly: false
                allowUserInvites: true
                allowMultipleSession: true
                passwordProtected: false
                password: null
                anonymous: false
                mayGetMemberList: ["member"]
                maxUsers: 30
                logging: true
            }
        ) {
            title
            description
            allowChangeSubject
            allowQueryUsers
            allowPrivateMessages
            allowVisitorStatus
            allowVisitorNickchange
            public
            publicList
            persistent
            moderated
            membersByDefault
            membersOnly
            allowUserInvites
            allowMultipleSession
            passwordProtected
            password
            anonymous
            mayGetMemberList
            maxUsers
            logging
        }
    }
}


Add User A to MUC with Affiliation as MEMBER: (NOT WORKING)
# called from GraphiQL with auth of User B within Request params (DOES NOT WORK)
# called from GraphiQL with auth of Admin within Request params (DOES NOT WORK)
mutation muc {
  muc {
    setUserAffiliation(
      affiliation: MEMBER,
      room: "desired-muc@group.localhost",
      user: "user-a@localhost"
    )
  }
}

Error details:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "muc",
        "setUserAffiliation"
      ],
      "message": "Given user does not have permission to set the member affiliation",
      "extensions": {
        "room": "desired-muc@group.localhost",
        "code": "not_allowed"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "muc": {
      "setUserAffiliation": null
    }
  }
}



Apparently, this is a confirmed bug in MongooseIM as detailed here.

After investigating, we found that the error only occurs when the access_admin option is set to "all". This appears to be a bug, and we'll add it to our backlog. When the option is not set, everything works properly.

